# Android Studio adding pictures with checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 10 different checkboxes and 10 different images linked to the checkbox.
1 image(which is not used for the checkboxes) is visible and the rest is invisible. 
I want my app to add the corresponding picture to the app when the checkbox has been checked. 
However, I can't find information regarding images and checkboxes online.

So I thought about an array of checkboxes with the image file.

```
        images[0] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[1] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[2] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[3] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[4] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[5] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[6] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[7] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[8] = R.drawable.imageID;
        images[9] = R.drawable.imageID;
```

i've seen allot of OnClick but I think OnCheck is better, but there isn't allot of information about onCheck..
Now i'm a bit lost :/

Can anyone help me get in the right direction?

thnx in advance

I've tried using the ClickListener but it only makes my checkbox invisible after i've checked and un-checked it.

```
    final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                 checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: why not use clickListener?

Comment: I've updated my post with something i've been working with.
The checkbox is now dissapearing after i'ved unchecked it.
Obviously because i've put the checkbox in the if/else statement, but how can I proceed this into ImageView pictures?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do with imageViews?

Comment: I wan't them to show in the app, after i've checked a checkbox

Comment: are you using a separate click listener for each checkbox?

Comment: Yeah, i'm currently trying to do it 1 step at a time. So i started with checkbox9. But eventually I have to get all 10 working.

I have to be close, but i'm missing some major steps ( I think).

If checkbox9 is checked
Get corresponding image from the drawable folder.
Make the image(which is currently INVISIBLE) visible when the checkbox is checked.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:

- Create a **custom view** that has an **imageview** and a **checkbox**.
- You **detect the click** on the custom view to **toogle the checkbox**
- Based on the **check status**, set the image visibility to true/false

Do try it out yourself first, you'll learn best when you figure it out yourself

Comment: I have tried this. 
And I have finally had succes with 1 image and 1 checkbox. 
It works great now.

But the next step is to make 9 more checkboxes and to make them all work.

Do I have to make an array for all the checkboxes, make a for loop to iterate trough the checkboxes and a for loop to iterate trough every checkbox and to check if they are check or not?

Did I miss anything or do I still need to add something?

Comment: if you are displaying it as a grid form (eg. like gallery) you can consider using gridview.